# Mathematica can't simplify asymptotic expressions containing constant symbols

Tags: simplifying-expressions, asymptotics

I want to calculate simple asymptotic expressions involving positive constant symbols ($a > 0$), such as
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \operatorname{sech}(a x) \sim 2 e^{-a x}$$

Surprisingly, the `Asymptotic` function of Mathematica can't calculate this limit.
The code

```
Assuming[a > 0, Asymptotic[Sech[a x], x -> ∞]]
```

returns `Sech[a x]`

while

```
Asymptotic[Sech[3 x], x -> ∞]
```

correctly returns `2 E^(-3 x)`

How can I get Mathematica to evaluate this asymptotic limit correctly?

Edit 1:

One hack is to replace $a$ with $\pi$, then calculate the asymptotic limit, then convert $\pi$ back to $a$.

```
Asymptotic[Sech[a x] /. a -> π, x -> ∞] /. π -> a
```

returns the desired limit `2 E^(-a x)`

Edit 2:

An actual example I am working on is

```
Assuming[a > 0, Asymptotic[-(1/2) Sech[1/2 x Sinh[a]]^2 Sinh[a]^2, x -> Infinity]]
```

So far only the $\pi$ trick works for this case, giving `-2 E^(-x Sinh[a]) Sinh[a]^2`.

Comment: That hack is very dubious, might work here but I'd expect all kinds of trouble in other situations. Best to find a more robust and correct solution.

Comment: The hack works better if you replace $a$ by EulerGamma instead of $\pi$. In fact, EulerGamma rarely pops up in actual calculations, while $\pi$ does quite often :)

Answer (score 7):

`TrigToExp` does the job

```
Assuming[a > 0, Asymptotic[TrigToExp[Sech[a *x]], x -> Infinity]]
```

> `2 E^(-a x)`

```
Assuming[a \[Element] Reals, Asymptotic[TrigToExp[Sech[x/a] + Sech[x*a]], x ->Infinity]]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[2 E^(-(x/a)), a > 1 && a^2 < 3]`

Comment: `Assuming[a > 0 && a < 1, 
 Asymptotic[TrigToExp[Sech[x/a] + Sech[x*a]], x -> Infinity]]` performs `ConditionalExpression[2 E^(-a x), 1/a^2 > 3]` and `Assuming[a > 1, 
 Asymptotic[TrigToExp[Sech[x/a] + Sech[x*a]], x -> Infinity]]` results in `ConditionalExpression[2 E^(-(x/a)), a^2 > 3]`.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer.

Comment: This is great. However, it's still not completely robust. An actual example I'm working on is `Assuming[a > 0, 
 Asymptotic[-(1/2) Sech[1/2 x Sinh[a]]^2 Sinh[a]^2, x -> Infinity]]`. Unfortunately `TrigToExp` doesn't help here. Though my π hack seems to work, giving `-2 E^(-x Sinh[a]) Sinh[a]^2`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Simplify[Refine[Asymptotic[Sech[a x], a x -> ∞], 
Assumptions -> Element[a,Reals]]]
```

Comment: FYI, if I omit the `Simplify` and the `Refine` I still get the same result.

Comment: Great, the function appears to work well!

Comment: This doesn't work for a more complicated expression like `Sech[a x] + Sech[x/a]`, where the dependence on `a` becomes more involved.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Mathematica simply cannot handle the asymptotics of `Sech` in general. When requesting the first order term, if you give it `TrigToExp@Sech[a x]` $= \dfrac{2}{e^{-a x}+e^{a x}}$ it's smart enough to deal with those exponentials. But if you try

```
Asymptotic[TrigToExp@Sech[a x], x -> ∞, Assumptions -> a > 0, SeriesTermGoal -> 2]
```

you'll find this doesn't work. This suggests that Mathematica can't actually generate the asymptotic expansion needed to deal with this. So for such things you'll just have to try to massage them into a form that Mathematica can digest.

For example, the next problem you left in a comment,
$$
-\frac{1}{2} \sinh ^2(a) \text{sech}^2\left(\frac{1}{2} x \sinh (a)\right)
$$
can be handled with

```
FullSimplify@Assuming[a>0,
Asymptotic[ExpandAll@TrigToExp[-(1/2) Sech[1/2 x Sinh[a]]^2 Sinh[a]^2],x->∞]]
```

which gives back
$$
2 \sinh ^2(a) (\sinh (x \sinh (a))-\cosh (x \sinh (a)))
$$